# Why would Tools toolbar of ArcMap be partially frozen?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Whilst using ArcMap one of my students 'froze' bits of the Tools Toolbar e.g. Zoom In/Out and Go To XY.

I couldn't figure out why.

In the end we reloaded the last saved file and it was fine.

Any ideas on what we did?

Answer (score 4):

they probably changed the properties of the extent of their map to "fixed extent".

Go to data frame properties > data frame , and make sure "extent" is on "automatic"